# Share browser session storage among multiple web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a requirement to share browser session storage among multiple web applications deployed on IIS such as `http://localhost/<app1>` and `http://localhost/<app2>`.

Is above scenario possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you **specifically** want to use session storage (vs say just looking up shared data in a SQL Server database)?

Comment: I am maintaining some information client side for some functionality which cannot be saved at server side. Hence session storage is used

Comment: localStorage in HTML5 has a shared space between applications from same Domain. Since both your applications have same domain, you should be able to access the localStorage variables across the applications in the client side.